# Why does jQuery swallow exceptions in $.ajax success callbacks?

Tags: jquery

It looks like jQuery 1.6.4 deliberately swallows exceptions in $.ajax success callbacks.

If I do this:

```
$.get('/', function() {console.log('doodoo');})
```

I get this in the (Chrome) console:

```
Object
doodoo
```

But if I do this,

```
$.get('/', function() {throw 'doodoo';})
```

I get no error in the console:

```
Object
```

A quick look at the jQuery source code shows this is obviously intentional:

```
try {
    while( callbacks[ 0 ] ) {
        callbacks.shift().apply( context, args );
    }
} catch(e) { }
```

Does anyone know why jQuery does this?

Comment: Hm, it seems that wasn't the case in jQuery 1.4. http://forum.jquery.com/topic/preventing-silent-failures-due-to-swallowed-exceptions#14737000000922550

Comment: Can't reproduce in 1.6.4 http://jsfiddle.net/9rCpV/ I also cannot find that code in 1.6.4 source here: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.js

Comment: Where are you viewing this source from? I checked all the official 1.6.4 tags in github and [none](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/215d096310663e2df302e0b13e82216a3ddde920/src/deferred.js#L57) [of](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/215d096310663e2df302e0b13e82216a3ddde920/src/deferred.js#L57) [them](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/19ceebd0f4817ddb2b6593d172e36e96d384aabb/src/deferred.js#L57) [have](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/455edf197add9a9ea21ac7cf4266784a083c74ef/src/deferred.js#L57) what you presented as a snippet from jQuery source...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing here, but the reason is probably because you would not be able to catch the error anyway. Since its a callback you would not be able to wrap it in a try/catch. If jQuery didn't catch it, your application would crash, which is most likely not what you want. If you need to check for errors wrap the code in a try/catch inside the callback.

```
try {
    $.get('/', function() {throw 'doodoo';})
} catch(e) {
    // this wont do anything, even if jQuery didn't catch the error
}

$.get('/', function() {
    try {
        throw 'doodoo';
    } catch(e) {
        // this is the proper way to do it
    }
})
```